# How to insert only last 4 digits of a textbox entry into database?

Tags: c#, string

I have an insert query that inserts the value of a textbox into a database table. It's a credit card number text box, so I only want to store the last 4 digits of the number. How can I do this? I'll show you what I have right now:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Number", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtCardNumber.Text;
```

I've tried adding " , -4" afterwards, but it doesn't allow that. Any help will be appreciated.

Note: Everything is inserted correctly otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String.Substring()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) method

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
>   specified character position.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Number", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtCardNumber.Text.Substring(txtCardNumber.Text.Length - 4);
```

Comment: The use of the second overload with a length is redundant in this case.

Comment: I deleted my last comment by accident, but thanks again. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

This is basic string manipulation.

To get the last four characters of any string:

```
theString.Substring(theString.Length - 4)
```

I suggest you take a good look at the different methods and properties defined on the [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

How about this??

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Number", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value =   txtCardNumber.Text.Substring(txtCardNumber.Text.Length - 4)
```

or you can also do this although not best solution..

```
var last4digits = (long.parse(txtCardNumber.Text)%10000).ToString();

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Number", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = last4digits;
```

Comment: Gaah. Parsing to long just to convert back to a string? _shudder_